# Copy files preserving folder structure

Tags: linux, file, shell

Could anyone help me to make a shell script to:

Having a certain folders and subfolders structure, copy from it to some other location all the files modified from a given date (or from a number of days on) and always preserving the folder structure.

So the result would be a subset of the origin having only the files that match the modified date condition. No need to place this new subset in any remote location... just another folder in the same file system.

Any idea on doing this?

I can think of some manual methods, but if there were something more "automatic", I'd like to know.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p "$2" && find . -type f ! -mtime +$1 | tar -cT - -f - |tar -C "$2" -xf -
```

usage:

```
copyscript <not-older-than-N-days> <destination dir>
```

Comment: just perfect! :) Now, I'd like to tell the script not to take into account some unnecessary folders in the root folder. How would you do that? Thanks :)