# Copying modified files and their file structure

Tags: linux, bash, exec, cp

I'm still new to linux scripting, so this might be a bit trivial.

As part of my script, I am trying to copy all the modified files (relative to the original backup I have made) to another folder while keeping the file structure. 
I have found this method:

```
find /SourceFolder/ -newer /BackupFOlder/ -exec cp --parents \{\} /Destination
```

However the above command does not work, giving me the error:
*find: missing argument to 'exec'*

Why doesn't this work?

I also found this:
[Copy files preserving folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008520/copy-files-preserving-folder-structure)

But I want to use *cp* command only.

Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-exec` option requires a `;` argument to tell it where the command ends, because you could have additional `find` options after it.

```
find /SourceFolder/ -newer /BackupFOlder/ -exec cp --parents {} /Destination \;
```

However, a better solution would be to use `rsync`:

```
rsync -a /SourceFolder /BackupFolder
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That seem to have done the trick. what is the difference between \{\} and {} part?

Comment: No difference. There's no need to escape those characters, they don't have any special meaning when there's nothing between them.

Comment: ok I see @Barmar. Thanks again. Also I agree rsync is a good option. But this is mainly for learning. Trying to do different scripts to get better at linux scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 tar cf - . | (cd <some other dir>; tar xfv -)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway of not using tar?

Comment: Yes - but I know `tar` is on all (most perhaps) unix systems

Comment: Yes, I have a 'restore' script as well which doesn't include 'tar'. This is mostly for learning purposes too. Trying to write the script with basic commands.

Comment: No it's not. That is why I am not using it. Given that I have found a lot of method using tar I am thinking of doing another script using tar.